# Send validation email from C++ application

Tags: c++, email, c++11, cross-platform, email-validation

I'm developing a cross-platform C++11 application and I need to send a validation email to a user-entered address to make sure his email account exists and is valid.

I know there are temporary mail services like *mailinator*, but honestly I feel like a validation email is a good approach in my case since it gives people malicious intention more work to do to circumvent the system and also goes well with the rest of the application (example: having the email address allow me to automatically send status updates to users).

I have searched on the internet but I haven't been able to find a **portable**, **cross-platform** way to achieve this, at least without introducing big dependencies.

How can this issue be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This email better not send from the client side. Write a server side http api and accept request from the client side application, then send the email on server.

Answer (score 2):

Given that we don't even have networking(!) in the C++11 standard (not to mention the POP3, SMTP or the IMAP protocols on the top of it), I am afraid you cannot do it without *"introducing big dependencies."*

If you are willing to use third party libraries

- [VMime](http://www.vmime.org/about.html)
- [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)
- [SmtpClient for Qt](https://github.com/bluetiger9/SmtpClient-for-Qt)
- [implementint the protocols](http://codingways.blogspot.co.at/2012/08/send-email-in-c-smtp-client-in-c.html) yourself on the top of [`boost::asio`](http://www.boost.org/libs/asio/)

are viable options depending on your needs and licensing requirements.